# gulp-webserver livereload doesn't work with css-Files

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-livereload

I'm using gulp-webserver.

If I'm manually editing .js or .html files in my build/-folder then livereload becomes active and refreshes the page. In opposite .css files are ignored - But why?

```
var webserver = require('gulp-webserver');

gulp.task('gulpWebserver', function () {
    return gulp.src('./build')
        .pipe(
            webserver({
                host: '0.0.0.0',
                https: true,
                livereload: true,
                open: 'https://localhost:8000'
            }));
});
```

Comment: i really doubt css are ignored, its just that for CSS it does not do a page reload/refresh. it just applies the css without reloading the page.. try changing background color of body to red and see if that works

Comment: You can have a "watch" task watching the css-file. If I run both the watch and webserver tasks in the default gulp task, it refreshes when changing the css.